# Resize Image object for Shape fill in KineticJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, kineticjs

I have an Image() object, which I need to resize. I am using it to [`fill` a shape](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-set-fill-with-kineticjs/) in `canvas`.

If I try to change it like `image.width = 300`, it doesn't resize. If I `console.log` it, it shows that only the html attribute has been changed.

Is there a way to edit the Image() size directly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this using the setting the `fill.scale` object with the properties `fill.scale.x` and `fill.scale.y` that you wish to apply to your image.

In the example, this could be done, for example like:

> ```
> var patternPentagon = new Kinetic.RegularPolygon({
>    x: 220,
>    y: stage.getHeight() / 2,
>    sides: 5,
>    radius: 70,
>    fill: {
>        scale: { x:0.5, y:0.5 },
>        image: images.darthVader,
>        offset: [-220, -70]
>    },
>    stroke: 'black',
>    strokeWidth: 4,
>    draggable: true
> ```
>
> });

You can see an example of this working [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jbalsas/Jz3nL/)